# Usage of shared_ptr between multiples threads / functions - IDS Peak API

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, ids

I am facing an issue with a share_ptr between 2 functions (main and svr.Get(...) of [HTTPlib](https://github.com/yhirose/cpp-httplib) library).

I'm declaring my pointer using :

```
std::shared_ptr<peak::core::DataStream> dataStream;
```

I'm initializing it using on the main :

```
dataStream = device->DataStreams().at(0)->OpenDataStream();
```

When I'm retrieving it on another function (GET function of HTTPLIB library), the address seems to be correct but the value is not the attended one :

```
EXCEPTION: Error-Code: 10 (PEAK_RETURN_CODE_INVALID_HANDLE) | Error-Description: dataStreamHandle is invalid!
```

The pointer seems to be dereferenced betweens the functions.
Where I am wrong ? What the right way to affect it and retrieve it in another function ?

Comment: Is the memory set to be shared that the pointer is pointing to?  I have used this in the past.  http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/shm_overview.7.html

Comment: Not directly the memory, but the stream object pointed by it. I've to use this object using a specific library so no way at all to use an shm for this kind of operation :(

Answer (score 0):

The manipulated object referenced by the pointer wasn't longer available due to ownership transfer. According the [CPP manual](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) :

> std::shared_ptr is a smart pointer that retains shared ownership of an object through a pointer. Several shared_ptr objects may own the same object. **The object is destroyed and its memory deallocated** when either of the following happens:
>
> the last remaining shared_ptr owning the object is destroyed;
> the last remaining shared_ptr owning **the object is assigned another pointer via operator=** or reset().

So, it's not an library issue but an allocation mistake.